# Trying to send an audio file and text to flask api but getting 400 bad request error

Tags: python, flask, post, audio, request

So, i am trying to send an audiofile and text as arguments to a flask api, it works fine when i send them through postman but i get a bad request error when i post it through python code.
Here is my python code:

```
import requests
import json
url= 'http://192.168.100.14:8000/v1/translate'
with open('/home/faizi/ai-chatbot-with-voice-driven-facial-animation/01_smalltalk_bot/game.wav', 'rb') as file:

 files = {'input_file': file}
 d = {"text":"hello, my name is faizan"}    
 req = requests.post(url, files=files, json=d)
 print(req.status_code)
 print(req.text)
```

And here is my flask api:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from flask import Blueprint, request, Response
import json
from Voice_Cloning_Module import demo_cli
from flask import send_file

app = Flask("foo")

@app.route('/v1/translate', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def translate_mbart():
  data = request.get_json()
  audio_file = request.files['input_file']
  audio_file.save("./bufferaudiofile/"+audio_file.filename)
  text = request.form['text']
  returnedfile = demo_cli.clone(text,"./bufferaudiofile/"+audio_file.filename)
  path_to_clonefile = returnedfile
  return send_file(
    path_to_clonefile,
    mimetype="audio/wav",
    as_attachment=True,
    attachment_filename="test.wav")






 if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I am getting 400 bad request error and i dont understand what could be the issue, it works fine in postman

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully send a wav file using the following code. I suggest stripping it back to bare bones and focussing on receiving the file to make sure nothing else is causing the issue.

**For the API:**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/main', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def main():

    file = request.files['file']
    print(file)

    return { "ok": True }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8000)
```

**And for the request:**

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost:8000/main'

with open('test_file.wav', 'rb') as wav:

    files = { "file": wav }
    d = { "body" : "Foo Bar" }

    req = requests.post(url, files=files, json=d)

    print(req.status_code)
    print(req.text)
```